# Now date with format in _timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, mapping, kibana, kibana-4

I want to index documents with the default value (now date) for the _timestamp, setting this field when elasticsearch indexes the document. I would like to save the _timestamp with a format so later I can use it in Kibana. So far I have tried many things, this being the simplest way to try to get the desired result:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_" : {
                      "_timestamp" : {"enabled" : true, "store" : "yes"}
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to give to this _timestamp a format such as "2015-02-25"?

With the actual mapping the value is in epoch timestamp:

```
fields: {
_timestamp: 1424895937428
}
```

Even if I don't give the desired format to the _timestamp, kibana doesn't recognize this value, so I can't query by this value.

So far I have also tried using the options like {"format" : "YYYY-MM-dd"} or {"index" : "analyzed" } in the mapping but no luck.

Is this that I'm trying even possible?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to pass data into elasticsearch?
I'm using fluentd right now, and having it read a list of json.
In my config, I have the time bit in source set-up as follows:

```
keys date, prot, srcip, srcport, country, org, dstip, dstport
time_key date
time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%:z
```

with date being the first field in the json being passed in, in the given format.
This worked out for me, and the value gets stored in an @timestamp field, and index will generally default to prefix-YYYY.MM.DD.

Comment: I'm using the Java API, and I would prefer not to add manually the timestamp.

Comment: Have you tried using [dynamic_date_formats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_date_formats)?